# How to get Email between random characters in query SQLserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have this string characters in database table,

```
select 'a:6:{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:4:"read";s:9:"your-name";s:7:"testing";s:10:"your-email";s:18:"tsting!@testng.com";s:10:"your-phone";s:9:"098098098";s:12:"your-message";s:20:"dfkjadsfh aljsdfasdf";s:20:"g-recaptcha-response";s:441:"03AHhf_52xlOGxCbcOqRtuiQABfbv9MjTpQ1bMW1gkaE8I1Ld9NIFhi0yVnh9FzqZDTLizhuahQyOIcofDPkSvYYT6gPZz7nCP2fU853pljiUgQjFZNZxTU1rzhm4gGMpuWJi4YXzKkKpU8KMfzkCngugZv3MlUl6VYN73W6OLfNDRfyfiQmVsJqk0IQqetBo2cnuMdPw_TxPNdW99bu-cnuv77ua0PgyDaqHeJwzKNrK4bHP797AyJdsvTaacCdwi_Pt-cbyQcnzRDsznow1VaiIjf1_eJd8_QpL2wAgFJsye5wb3sYnrpexat6ymMHZrDchhHNKTSobWySjQd3UNEpF3NH73wV2RwpYYuJp2h8sd7xLE9JgKkV0DxK7KLfqS7Oy22REdsKILkI-iqfgaV71wFUWrcYcmIm-JAJqVm-CoR4JB-rOZcSk";}'
```

how can I get email address only between some character above with query
please help me !

Comment: use unserialise, you will get the data in an array.

Comment: SQL Server has fairly weak regex support, which is what you really need here.  But more to the point, what is this unnormalized string doing there in the first place?

Comment: it seems like a Json data, how to do unserialise by sql query?

Comment: Is the mail id always in **s18**?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(500) 

SET @str = 
'a:6:{s:9:"your-name";s:7:"testing";s:10:"your-email";s:18:"**tsting!@testng.com**";s:10:"your-phone";s:9:"25625222";}' 

SELECT Substring(@str, Patindex('%"**%', @str) + 3, Patindex('%**%', 
              Substring(@str, Patindex('%"**%', @str) + 4, Len(@str)))) AS Email
```

Output

```
+--------------------+
| Email              |
+--------------------+
| tsting!@testng.com |
+--------------------+
```

Comment: you are really cool bro.. its work but in other table I have data like 'a:6:{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:4:"read";s:9:"your-name";s:7:"testing";s:10:"your-email";s:18:"tsting!@testng.com";s:10:"your-phone";s:9:"098098098";s:12:"your-message";s:20:"dfkjadsfh aljsdfasdf";s:20:"g-recaptcha-response";s:441:"03AHhf_52xlOGxCbcOqRtuiQABfbv9MjTpQ1bMW1gkaE8I1Ld9NIFhi0yVnh9FzqZDTLizhuahQyOIcofDPkSvYYT6gPZz7nCP2fU853pljiUgQjFZNZxTU1rzhm4gGMpuWJi4YXzKkKpU8KMfzkCngugZv3MlUl6VYN73W6OLfNDRfyfiQmVsJqk0IQqetBo2cnuMdPw_TxPNdW99bu-cnuv77ua0PgyDaqHeJwzKNrK4bHP797AyJdsvTaacCdwi_";}'  could you help me one more time?

Comment: its really going to be tough for you if the string is not in a fixed format.